# Call a function inside onther function (function($) {}

Tags: jquery, function, call

To avoid jQuery conflicts with '$' i have some functions inside

```
(function($) {});
```

an i want to call it from outside the function. Is there any possibility?

looks like this:

```
whatever();

(function($) {

 function whatever(){};

});
```

Thanks you very much in Advance...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create multiple instances of IIFE Javascript module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33147220/how-to-create-multiple-instances-of-iife-javascript-module)

Comment: Thats no duplicate...

Comment: Yet the answer below is almost identical to Quentin's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/33147338/852866 but it lacks a tiny but important detail.

Answer (score 0):

This is a way to create a wrapper that exposes some functions while it keeps other functions private.

```js
var myWrapper = function($) {

  var wrapper = {};
  wrapper.whatever = function (){
   console.log("whatever");
  };
  return wrapper;
}(jQuery);

myWrapper.whatever();
```

Comment: i am afraid, this is not possible, als my function($) is getting not executed anymore,,,

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33147338/852866 It should be `var myWrapper = (function($) {...blah, blah...})(jQuery)`

Comment: Fixed by adding jQuery parameter.